# What does this problem mean? And why is C the correct answer and not B?

Tags: word-problem

So I tried to solve this problem in the 1955 AHSME:

In order to pass $B$ going $40$ mph on a two-lane highway, $A$, going $50$ mph, must gain $30$ feet. Meantime, $C, 210$ feet from $A$, is headed toward him at $50$ mph. If $B$ and $C$ maintain their speeds, then, in order to pass safely, $A$ must increase his speed by:

$\textbf{(A)}\ \text{30 mph}\qquad\textbf{(B)}\ \text{10 mph}\qquad\textbf{(C)}\ \text{5 mph}\qquad\textbf{(D)}\ \text{15 mph}\qquad\textbf{(E)}\ \text{3 mph}$

I do not understand some parts of the problem clearly, but I did try to solve the problem. So I came up with answer B. But the correct answer is C. After some research, C only makes sense if the cars are mathematical points, but if they have a volume, then C shouldn't be correct.

So, why is C the correct answer? And why isn't B the correct answer?

Comment: As any driving instructor or safety officer would tell you: The only way to pass safely in this situation is to wait for car A to go by!

Comment: Unless the length of A and B are specified, there is no choice but to treat all vehicles as points and to assume that sideways motion is instantaneous.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ be speed of $A$ at which it can pass safely. Then we can show that
$$\frac{210}{50+x} = \frac{30}{x-40}=t,$$ where $t$ is time of passing.
Solving this equation gives us $x = 55$, and if A was going $50$ mph, then answer is $55-50=5 \to C$

Comment: I got this answer too but such an answer is unrealistic physically. On the other hand, if (B) is the correct answer, then so are both (A) and (D). Thus the problem itself was NOT well formulated at least in terms of the real world.